# How to add new value to the json format

Tags: json, react-native

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, TextInput,Button} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';

export default class Asst extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        "email": "hh@gmail.com",
        "goal": "Aptitude",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "skillName": "Linear ALgebra",
                "start_date": "05-05-2020 11:07",
                "end_date": "05-11-2020 11:20",
            },
            {
                "skillName": "Ratios",
                "start_date": "10-09-2020 11:00",
                "end_date": "14-05-2020 07:00",

            }
        ],
    };
      this.AddSkill = this.AddSkill.bind(this);
      this.handleChanged = this.handleChanged.bind(this);


  }

  AddSkill(skill) {
      console.log("added task");
      this.state.tasks.push(skill);
      this.setState({tasks: this.state.tasks})
  }
  handleChanged(event) {
    this.setState({goal: event}); 
}
onsave=()=>{

  alert('Ready to save');
}
  listitem(){
    return this.state.tasks.map((t) => {
      return (
<View>


  <ScrollView>

                <ScrollView horizontal={true} style={{paddingBottom:20,paddingTop:20,borderColor:'black'}}>
                <Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>{t.skillName+"                       "}</Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize:20,backgroundColor:'springgreen'}}>{t.start_date+"     "}</Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize:20,backgroundColor:'lightsalmon'}}>{t.end_date}</Text>
              </Text>
              </ScrollView>

              </ScrollView>
              </View>
            )
          })   
  }
  render() {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}></Text>

        <View>
            <TaskNameForm onAddTask={this.AddSkill} />
            <Text style={styles.title}>{this.state.goal}</Text>
            <ScrollView horizontal={true} style={{paddingBottom:20,paddingTop:20,borderColor:'black'}}>
                <Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>Task Name                  </Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize:20,backgroundColor:'springgreen'}}>      Start Date     </Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize:20,backgroundColor:'lightsalmon'}}>     End Date     </Text>
              </Text>
              </ScrollView>
        </View>
        <View>
          <ScrollView vertical={true}>
            {this.listitem()}
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
        <Button 
                  title="SAVE" 
                  onPress={this.onsave}
              />
        </SafeAreaView>

      );
  }
}
export class TaskNameForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value: ''};

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.dateChange = this.dateChange.bind(this);


  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
      const skillList = this.props.skillList;
      event.preventDefault();
      const skill = {id:Date.now(),name: this.state.TextInputvalue, 
      dueDate: new Date(),date:this.state.date,date1:this.state.date1};
      this.props.onAddTask(skill);
      this.setState({TextInputvalue:''})
  }

  handleChange(event) {

      this.setState({TextInputvalue: event});

  }
  componentHideAndShow = () => {
    this.setState(previousState => ({ content: !previousState.content }))
  }
  dateChange(event){
      this.setState({date :event.target.value});
      this.setState({date1 :event.target.value});


  }
  render() {
      return(
        <View> 
            <TextInput  
                    style={{height: 40,backgroundColor: 'azure', fontSize: 20}}  
                    placeholder={'Enter'}  
                    value={this.state.TextInputvalue}
                    onChangeText={this.handleChange}
                />  

                <DatePicker 
                    style={{width: 300}}
                    date={this.state.date} 
                    mode="datetime" 
                    placeholder="start date"
                    format="DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm"
                    minDate="01-01-2020"
                    maxDate="01-01-2030"
                    confirmBtnText="Done"
                    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                    customStyles={{
                    dateInput: {
                      marginLeft: 36
                    }
                  }}
                onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date: date})}}
                />
                 <DatePicker 
                    style={{width: 300}}
                    date={this.state.date1} 
                    mode="datetime" 
                    placeholder="end date"
                    format="DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm"
                    minDate="01-01-2020"
                    maxDate="01-01-2030"
                    confirmBtnText="Done"
                    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                    customStyles={{
                    dateInput: {
                      marginLeft: 36
                    }
                  }}
                onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date1: date})}}
                />
           <Button 
                  title="Submit" 
                  onPress={this.handleSubmit}
              />

        </View>
      );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: '100%',
    paddingVertical: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,

    alignContent:'center',
    position: 'absolute', 
    top: 0, left: 0, 
    right: 0, bottom: 0,
  },
  title:{
    fontSize:30,
  },
  containers: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
  textInput: {
    width: '90%',
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginBottom: 30,
    borderColor: 'gray', 
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    fontSize: 16,
}
});
```

Here is the output I got:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5NWA.jpg)

Like when I tried adding it is showing like undefined.

Comment: It's unclear what the actual question is. Also, could you provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example?

Answer (score 0):

Using Spread Syntax ( …three dots) you can add new node.

```
let  data= {
        "email": "hh@gmail.com",
        "goal": "Aptitude",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "skillName": "Linear ALgebra",
                "start_date": "05-05-2020 11:07",
                "end_date": "05-11-2020 11:20",
            },
            {
                "skillName": "Ratios",
                "start_date": "10-09-2020 11:00",
                "end_date": "14-05-2020 07:00",

            }
        ],
    };
data = { ...people, skills: 'react'};
```

Output will be

```
data = {
        "email": "hh@gmail.com",
        "goal": "Aptitude",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "skillName": "Linear ALgebra",
                "start_date": "05-05-2020 11:07",
                "end_date": "05-11-2020 11:20",
            },
            {
                "skillName": "Ratios",
                "start_date": "10-09-2020 11:00",
                "end_date": "14-05-2020 07:00",

            }
        ],
    "skills": 'react'

    }
```